# Change Eclipse Configuration Of Imported Maven Projects

Tags: eclipse, maven

We have a large multi module maven project that builds on the command line. I am trying to import into eclipse with the maven import project approach and it imports fine. However, the resultant eclipse projects have a bunch of options that slow downs builds etc. I would like to be able to configure the maven project import to disable some options (like CDI validation ) and not have 6 builder configured. I would prefer to not have to go into each project and make a series of changes.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to post this as an answer, because I can't solve the problem the way you want to.

I've run into similar situations, like ensuring that all projects have Maven Workspace Resolution disabled.  My conclusion was, there's no way to do this, in Eclipse.  I simply have scripts that I run from the shell that "fix things".  Make sure that your script is written carefully, so it doesn't get confused or munge the file (I also have it copy the original to a ".bak" file). At least if you code it in a script, it won't be as tedious, and might be less error prone.